# logout from google and facebook using angular

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, npm, google-signin, logout

after **login** to **Facebook** and **Google** using **[this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-social-login)**

I am unable to signout for Google and Facebook  with this code.

```
this.authService.signOut();
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Can anyone please help me!

Comment: Are you trying to logout from Facebook and Google with your code? You can't logout from FB or Google with your code. But you can logout from your App because you've all control over your App not FB or Google.

Comment: thank you , yes, I am trying that like in Android, but how can delete my app from google and facebook account, Hopefully it won't manually :) , is there any code for that !

Comment: These might help you https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/92, https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/24

Comment: thank you so much, can u reply with that, Dev FaceBook cache
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxxxxxx/settings/basic/
App Domains must be Empty
Privacy Policy URL must be Empty
Site URL is http://localhost:4200 (answer fromp that link https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/92 ) so I can accept it

Comment: Yes, I am also facing same issue, it get logged in easily but its not getting logout.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this
this.authService.signOut(true);

Comment: Welcome @Naman on StackOverflow, It would be great if you can explain about the parameter. It will help others to understand what is the exact use of it.

Comment: Tested and not working regardless with or without true. The authState will stay returning valid user value until you refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { SocialUser , SocialAuthService } from 'angularx-social-login';
...
socialUser: SocialUser;
constructor(private socialAuthService: SocialAuthService) {}
...
signup(){
...
  this.socialUser = userData;
...
}
logout() {
  ... 
  if(this.socialUser !== null) {
     this.socialAuthService.signOut();
  }
}
```

This worked for me to Logout from Google using angularx-social-login npm module [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login)